# Using import with reactjs

Tags: javascript, import, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi I'm following a few different reactjs tutorials.

eg http://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

so how does one avoid

```
SyntaxError: modules are not implemented yet    

import React from "react/addons";
```

I assume I need to preload a shim or something (compile from es6 to legacy js?). 
Or is there another method for using import (outside of es6)?

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) in some fashion to transpile or process your source. It looks like the project you referenced is using [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) via webpack.